# Trying to split phone number column into 3 separate columns depending on phone type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with Microsoft Adventureworks 2017 sample database. I'm trying to get the employees phone numbers into 3 different columns depending on the type either home, work and cell.

I've been working on it and made some changes to make it look like this currently

```
Department Lastname Firstname PhoneNumber Email
```

But I want to make it into this

```
Department Lastname Firstname Cell Home Work Email
```

This is the code I've tried with so far but i'm having a hard time getting the numbers in the right column

```
select 
    ce.PhoneNumber as 'Cell', 
    Ho.PhoneNumber as 'Home', 
    wo.PhoneNumber as 'Work'
from
    (select ppp.phonenumber, pnt.name as 'Cell'
     from Person.PhoneNumberType pnt 
     join Person.PersonPhone ppp on pnt.PhoneNumberTypeID = ppp.PhoneNumberTypeID
     join HumanResources.Employee he on he.BusinessEntityID = ppp.BusinessEntityID) as ce
join
    (select ppp.phonenumber, pnt.name as 'Home'
     from Person.PhoneNumberType pnt 
     join Person.PersonPhone ppp on pnt.PhoneNumberTypeID = ppp.PhoneNumberTypeID
     join HumanResources.Employee he on he.BusinessEntityID = ppp.BusinessEntityID) as Ho on ce.PhoneNumber = Ho.PhoneNumber
join
    (select ppp.phonenumber, pnt.name as 'Work'
     from Person.PhoneNumberType pnt 
     join Person.PersonPhone ppp on pnt.PhoneNumberTypeID = ppp.PhoneNumberTypeID
     join HumanResources.Employee he on he.BusinessEntityID = ppp.BusinessEntityID) as Wo on ce.PhoneNumber = Wo.PhoneNumber
```

And I'm not sure how I should add that code to this

```
select 
    hd.Name as Avdelning, 
    pp.LastName as Efternamn, pp.FirstName as Förnamn, 
    pt.PhoneNumber, pe.EmailAddress
from
    Person.Person PP 
join 
    Person.PersonPhone PT on pp.BusinessEntityID = pt.BusinessEntityID
join 
    HumanResources.Employee HE on pp.BusinessEntityID = he.BusinessEntityID
join 
    Person.EmailAddress pe on pp.BusinessEntityID = pe.BusinessEntityID
join 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory hed on pp.BusinessEntityID = hed.BusinessEntityID
join 
    HumanResources.Department hd on hed.DepartmentID = hd.DepartmentID
where 
    EndDate is null
order by 
    LastName, FirstName
```

Comment: Have you looked at `PIVOT`? If you want to do something with a join approach you'll need some where clauses or filtered joins for those 3 fields, I think.

Answer (score 1):

We do not have the full DDL for each of the tables. Yet from what we understand this may work. So, give this a try.

```
-- revised Feb 03 8:45am  add BusinessEntityID & MAX to select, add GroupBy-s...
select 
    pp.BusinessEntityID,
    hd.Name as Avdelning, 
    pp.LastName as Efternamn, pp.FirstName as Förnamn, 
    --pt.PhoneNumber, 
    MAX(Case When PT.PhoneNumberTypeID = 'Cell' Then PT.phonenumber Else Null End) as Cell,
    MAX(Case When PT.PhoneNumberTypeID = 'Home' Then PT.phonenumber Else Null End) as Home,
    MAX(Case When PT.PhoneNumberTypeID = 'Work' Then PT.phonenumber Else Null End) as Work,
    pe.EmailAddress
from
    Person.Person PP 
join 
    Person.PersonPhone PT           on pp.BusinessEntityID = pt.BusinessEntityID
--join 
--    HumanResources.Employee HE            on pp.BusinessEntityID = he.BusinessEntityID
join 
    Person.EmailAddress pe          on pp.BusinessEntityID = pe.BusinessEntityID
join 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory hed on pp.BusinessEntityID = hed.BusinessEntityID
join 
    HumanResources.Department hd        on hed.DepartmentID = hd.DepartmentID
where 
    EndDate is null
group by
    pp.BusinessEntityID,
    hd.Name,
    pp.LastName,
    pp.FirstName,
    pe.EmailAddress
order by 
    LastName, FirstName
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer appreciate it.

This does feel right only that i get the error message

"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Cell' to data type int."

I tried converting it to char(1) but then it's just blank and i dont get any numbers?

Comment: What are the values and meanings for the column PhoneNumberTypeID ?  Is it something like 1 = xxx, and 2 = yyy?  What is the value for Cell, for xxx?